# Passing an <input> element's value as the parameter to an attached event function returning undefined

Tags: html, angular, events

**EDIT:** Okay, I wasn't thinking that hard, and obviously passing `this.value` in the template won't be doing what I want it to do. My question is: is there a way in Angular for an element to refer to it's own properties, like how `this.value` would work in normal html?

~

I have the following input variable in my Angular project:

```
<input 
   mdInput 
   [value]   = "this.currentFrameProperties.index ? this.currentFrameProperties.index : 0"
   (change)  = "OnFrameChanged(this.value)"
>
```

I have placed a breakpoint in my OnFrameChanged function and determined that the parameter passed to it is undefined. I am confused though, why does `this.value` not return the value property of the input element?

Here is my OnFrameChanged() function:

```
private OnFrameChanged(frame : number) : void
{
    // At this position, frame is undefined
    this.webSocketService.send( "jump to frame " + frame);
}
```

Ideas of what is going awry?

Answer (score 1):

You should not bind to this in the template. Instead do the following:

```
<input 
   mdInput 
   [value]   = "currentFrameProperties.index ? currentFrameProperties.index : 0"
   (change)  = "onFrameChanged($event)"
>
```

and use camelCase for method names

Comment: The event is a whole event object though. I'll have to bind to $event.target.value, or something along those lines? 

p.s. regarding camelCase functions, I'm just following my company spec, lol.

Comment: Also, do you know of any way in Angular for an element to refer to itself or its own properties, instead of using `this`? (which is now see obviously why it didn't work)

Comment: If you dont use ngModel that's probably what you should use. this works in the classes not tamplates. just skip the word 'this.' and Angular will do the binding anyway

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the `this` keyword won't work in an Angular template, but to recreate this behavior, we can just give the input element a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-)!

This gives the template the ability to reference values within this element, like so:

```
<input 
   #frameInputElement
   mdInput 
   [value]   = "this.currentFrameProperties.index ? this.currentFrameProperties.index : 0"
   (change)  = "OnFrameChanged(frameInputElement.value)"
>
```